# Как последовательно открыть несколько файлов txt и проверить значения в них?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, ос

У меня есть программа способная расшифровывать зашифрованные файлы. В начале после запуска необходимо загрузить ранее созданный ключ с ответами, нажав на кнопку **"Загрузить ключи с ответами"** после чего выбрать нужный ключ, данные из ключа автоматически загрузятся в `lineEdit`. После чего, по моей задумке, пользователь вводит директорию в которой находятся файлы для проверки *(их может быть огромное множество, а может быть и один)*, после чего нажимает на кнопку **"Начать проверку работ"**, после чего программа должна сама по очереди открыть все файлы в этой директории с расширением `.txt`, и проверить полученные данные из ранее загруженного ключа и данных располагающихся в файле *(файлы тоже зашифрованы и расшифровываются точно также как и ранее загруженный ключ)*, программа проверяет каждую строку, по итогу программа выводит в другой файл `.txt` *(находящийся в другой директории)* все данные из файла *(в расшифрованном виде)* и баллы. Пример вывода `№1: 1, №2: 0` *(и так 12 раз)*.

Текста много, но только так можно объяснить, что я пытаюсь сделать, но как то даже не приходит в голову идей как это реализовать.

**main.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from crypto import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import rsa
import base64
import os

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.answers = []

        self.setWindowTitle("Automatic OGE verification system ver.00.09.56")
        self.btn_generate_keys.clicked.connect(self.func_generate_keys)

        (self.key_pub, self.key_priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.information)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.app_key_task)

    def verification(self):
        pass

    def information(self):
        if not os.path.exists('key_pub.pem'):
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("Ошибка")
            msg.setInformativeText('ВНИМАНИЕ! Публичный ключ не найден'
                                   'Попробуйте сгенерировать новый ключ.')
            msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
            msg.exec_()
            return

        with open('key_pub.pem', "rb") as f:
            _key_pub = f.read()

        key_pub = self.key_pub.load_pkcs1(_key_pub)

        self.bit_key = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        self.directory_key_check = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        self.directory_file_check = self.lineEdit_15.text()
        self.name_file_key = self.lineEdit_16.text()
        self.directory_check_file = self.lineEdit_17

        self.key_task(key_pub)

    def key_task(self, key_pub):
        self.number_1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.number_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.number_3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.number_4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        self.number_5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.number_6 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.number_7 = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        self.number_8 = self.lineEdit_8.text()
        self.number_9 = self.lineEdit_9.text()
        self.number_10 = self.lineEdit_10.text()
        self.number_11 = self.lineEdit_11.text()
        self.number_12 = self.lineEdit_12.text()

        self.key_task_crypto(key_pub)

    def key_task_crypto(self, key_pub):
        self.number_1_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_1.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_2_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_2.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_3_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_3.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_4_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_4.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_5_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_5.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_6_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_6.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_7_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_7.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_8_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_8.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_9_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_9.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_10_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_10.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_11_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_11.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_12_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_12.encode('utf8'), key_pub)

        self.load_key_task_crypto()

    def load_key_task_crypto(self):
        k = [self.number_1_crypto, self.number_2_crypto, self.number_3_crypto, self.number_4_crypto,
             self.number_5_crypto, self.number_6_crypto, self.number_7_crypto, self.number_8_crypto,
             self.number_9_crypto, self.number_10_crypto, self.number_11_crypto, self.number_12_crypto]

        directory_save_key = self.directory_key_check +  self.name_file_key

        with open(directory_save_key, "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join(base64.b64encode(item).decode('utf8') for item in k))

        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setText("Информация")
        msg.setInformativeText('Данные ключей ответов сохранены')
        msg.setWindowTitle("Информация")
        msg.exec_()

    def app_key_task(self):
        if not os.path.exists('key_priv.pem'):
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("Ошибка")
            msg.setInformativeText('ВНИМАНИЕ! Приватный ключ не найден'
                                   'Попробуйте сгенерировать новый ключ.')
            msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
            msg.exec_()
            return

        with open('key_priv.pem', "rb") as f:
            _key_priv = f.read()

        key_priv = self.key_priv.load_pkcs1(_key_priv)

        directory_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, ".", "*.txt")
        if not directory_file:
            return

        with open(directory_file, "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            decrypted = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(line.strip()), key_priv)

            self.answers.append(decrypted.decode('utf8'))

        name_file = os.path.basename(directory_file)
        directory_file = os.path.dirname(directory_file) + "/"

        self.lineEdit.setText(self.answers[0])
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(self.answers[1])
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(self.answers[2])
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(self.answers[3])
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(self.answers[4])
        self.lineEdit_6.setText(self.answers[5])
        self.lineEdit_7.setText(self.answers[6])
        self.lineEdit_8.setText(self.answers[7])
        self.lineEdit_9.setText(self.answers[8])
        self.lineEdit_10.setText(self.answers[9])
        self.lineEdit_11.setText(self.answers[10])
        self.lineEdit_12.setText(self.answers[11])

        self.lineEdit_14.setText(directory_file)
        self.lineEdit_16.setText(name_file)

    def func_generate_keys(self):
        save_key_pub = self.key_pub.save_pkcs1()
        with open('key_pub.pem', "wb") as f:
            f.write(save_key_pub)

        save_key_priv = self.key_priv.save_pkcs1()
        with open('key_priv.pem', "wb") as f:
            f.write(save_key_priv)

        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setText("Информация")
        msg.setInformativeText('Ключи шифрования и дешифровки созданны.'
                               'Отправте публичный ключ участникам ОГЭ')
        msg.setWindowTitle("Информация")
        msg.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**crypto.py:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WOF20K3ulmFt0HorWf0Nj8CADTzUAX3l/view?usp=sharing

**Update:**
Если упростить задачу и исключить дешифрование файлов, то можно представить так, на входе получаем список с переменными, в которых хранятся данные из строк, выглядит это примерно так:

> Первые 12 переменных-это и есть ответы на задание, дальше идет
> информация о том, кто делал работу, дд.мм.гг, регион, код ОО, номер
> класса, литера класса, код ППЭ, номер аудитории, номер варианта, код
> предмета, название предмета, номер КИМ, фамилия, имя, отчество,
> серия(паспорта), номер(паспорта).

Каждый из пунктов перечисленных выше, находится на отдельных строчках.

Что бы начать проверку, нужно указать директорию где находятся файлы для проверки, после чего указать директорию куда сохранятся проверенные файлы и ввести в поля `lineEdit` правильные ответы, и в конце нажать на кнопку "Начать проверку", после чего программа переберет все файлы и в директории сохранения проверенных файлов будет создан новый текстовый файл по каждой работе, пример вывода данных:

```
№1: 0, №2: 1, №3: 1, №4: 1, №5: 0, №6: 0, №7: 0, №8: 0, №9: 1, №10: 1, №11: 1, №12: 1

№1: 120/№1: 120, №2: 1/№2: 1 *(так выводится правильная и неправильная комбинация, то есть первое число-это то, что ввел экзаменуемый, а второе число-это правильный ответ)*
```

Ниже располагаются остальные данные, перечисленные выше.

**main.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from FOTO import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ver.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ver.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 484)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 10, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 11, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_11, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_15, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_14, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_13, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_12, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_16, 11, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_16 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_16.setObjectName("lineEdit_16")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_16, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_18 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_18.setObjectName("lineEdit_18")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_18, 8, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_19 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_19.setObjectName("lineEdit_19")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_19, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_17 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_17.setObjectName("lineEdit_17")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_17, 7, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_10, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_9, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_32 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_32.setObjectName("lineEdit_32")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_32, 12, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_17, 12, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_33 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_33.setObjectName("lineEdit_33")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_33, 13, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_18, 13, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 320, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "12"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория файлов</p><p>для проверки</p></body></html>"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория </p><p>провереных файлов</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать проверку"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @S.Nick поможете с вопросом?

Comment: Settings, вам надо научиться составлять минимальные примеры, которые демонстрируют только интересующую вас проблему. С системой шифрования вы, я так полагаю, уже разобрались и не надо каждый раз об этом писать. Составьте пример, который содержит несколько lineEdit, в которые надо будет что-то написать. Объясните что туда надо писать, это будут ответы на какие-то вопросы? После нажатия на кнопку эти данные из lineEdit сверяются с информацией, которые содержатся в каких-то файлах. Покажите пример содержимого этих файлов, это какие-то правильные ответы? Каков принцип сверки? и т.д. ...

Comment: @S.Nick я упростил задачу (вроде как), посмотрите теперь.

Comment: Settings, да это уже лучше. Sorry, я действительно не понимаю что и как вы хотите проверять. Зачем вам перебирать все файлы? Я так понимаю, что у вас есть файлы, которые надо проверить, которые кроме всего прочего содержат ответы по какому-то варианту какого-то предмета. И есть файлы по какому-то варианту какого-то предмета, которые содержат правильные ответы. И нужно сопоставить данные файлы и сделать анализ правильность ответов студента и результаты анализа записать в новый файл к каком-то формате. В общем вам надо все подробно рассказать и показать примеры файлов и какой алгоритм сверки...

Comment: @S.Nick вы поняли все верно, про алгоритм я не знаю, по этому и написал.

Comment: @S.Nick есть продвижения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы реализовать данный процесс необходимо задать директорию в которой будет проводится проверка. После этого код посчитает количество файлов с расширением `.txt` в данной директории и запишет их полный путь *(ВАЖНО! В директории для проверки не должно быть посторонних файлов не содержащих зашифрованное сообщение)*. А после через цикл `for` перебираем все файлы и записываем результаты в новые файлы `.txt`.

**main.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from crypto import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import rsa
import base64
import os

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.answers = []
        self.file_names = []
        self.student_answers = []
        self.result = []
        self.comparison_responses = []

        self.result_OGE = 0

        self.setWindowTitle("Automatic OGE verification system ver.00.09.56")
        self.btn_generate_keys.clicked.connect(self.func_generate_keys)

        (self.key_pub, self.key_priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.information)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.app_key_task)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.file_names_app)

    def file_names_app(self):
        self.directory_file_check = self.lineEdit_15.text()

        try:
            for file in os.listdir(self.directory_file_check):
                if file.endswith(".txt"):
                    self.file_names.append(os.path.join(self.directory_file_check, file))

            print(self.file_names)

        except:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("Ошибка")
            msg.setInformativeText('ВНИМАНИЕ! Поле "Директория файлов для проверки" не заполнено'
                                   'Заполните поле для начала проверки')
            msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
            msg.exec_()

        finally:
            self.verification()

    def verification(self):

        score_file = len(self.file_names)
        file_order = 0

        print(score_file)
        print(file_order)

        for i in range(0, score_file):
            with open(self.file_names[file_order], "r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                decrypted = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(line.strip()), self.key_priv)
                self.student_answers.append(decrypted.decode('utf8'))

            self.number_1 = self.lineEdit.text()
            self.number_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
            self.number_3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
            self.number_4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
            self.number_5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
            self.number_6 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
            self.number_7 = self.lineEdit_7.text()
            self.number_8 = self.lineEdit_8.text()
            self.number_9 = self.lineEdit_9.text()
            self.number_10 = self.lineEdit_10.text()
            self.number_11 = self.lineEdit_11.text()
            self.number_12 = self.lineEdit_12.text()

            if str(self.number_1) == (self.student_answers[0]):
                self.result.append("№1: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№1: 0")

            if str(self.number_2) == (self.student_answers[1]):
                self.result.append("№2: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№2: 0")

            if str(self.number_3) == (self.student_answers[2]):
                self.result.append("№3: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№3: 0")

            if str(self.number_4) == (self.student_answers[3]):
                self.result.append("№4: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№4: 0")

            if str(self.number_5) == (self.student_answers[4]):
                self.result.append("№5: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№5: 0")

            if str(self.number_6) == (self.student_answers[5]):
                self.result.append("№6: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№6: 0")

            if str(self.number_7) == (self.student_answers[6]):
                self.result.append("№7: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№7: 0")

            if str(self.number_8) == (self.student_answers[7]):
                self.result.append("№8: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№8: 0")

            if str(self.number_9) == (self.student_answers[8]):
                self.result.append("№9: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№9: 0")

            if str(self.number_10) == (self.student_answers[9]):
                self.result.append("№10: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№10: 0")

            if str(self.number_11) == (self.student_answers[10]):
                self.result.append("№11: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№11: 0")

            if str(self.number_12) == (self.student_answers[11]):
                print(self.number_12, self.student_answers[11])
                self.result.append("№12: 1")
                self.result_OGE += 1
            else:
                self.result.append("№12: 0")

            self.result.append("№13: ЗАДАНИЕ ПРОВЕРЯЕТСЯ ЭКСПЕРТОМ")
            self.result.append("№14: ЗАДАНИЕ ПРОВЕРЯЕТСЯ ЭКСПЕРТОМ")
            self.result.append("№15: ЗАДАНИЕ ПРОВЕРЯЕТСЯ ЭКСПЕРТОМ")

            self.comparison_responses.append(self.number_1 + "/" + self.student_answers[0] + "," + self.number_2 + "/"
                                             + self.student_answers[1] + "," +
                                             self.number_3 + "/" + self.student_answers[2] + "," + self.number_4 + "/"
                                             + self.student_answers[3] + "," +
                                             self.number_5 + "/" + self.student_answers[4] + "," + self.number_6 + "/"
                                             + self.student_answers[5] + "," +
                                             self.number_7 + "/" + self.student_answers[6] + "," + self.number_8 + "/"
                                             + self.student_answers[7] + "," +
                                             self.number_9 + "/" + self.student_answers[8] + "," + self.number_10 + "/"
                                             + self.student_answers[9] + "," +
                                             self.number_11 + "/" + self.student_answers[
                                                 10] + "," + self.number_12 + "/"
                                             + self.student_answers[11]
                                             )

            if self.result_OGE >= 0 and self.result_OGE <= 4:
                self.score = 2
            elif self.result_OGE >= 5 and self.result_OGE <= 11:
                self.score = 3
            elif self.result_OGE >= 12 and self.result_OGE <= 16:
                self.score = 4
            elif self.result_OGE >= 17 and self.result_OGE <= 19:
                self.score = 5
            else:
                self.score = "Ошибка расчета оценки, обратитесь к техническому специалисту"

            record_in_file = open(self.student_answers[23] + "_" + self.student_answers[24] + "_" +
                                  self.student_answers[25] + "_" + self.student_answers[19] + ".txt", "a")

            record_in_file.write("ПРОВЕРКА ВЫПОЛНЕНА В Automatic OGE verification system ver.00.09.56 " + "\n" + "\n" +
                                 "Copyright  Alexandrov Andrey" + "\n" + "\n" + str(self.result) + "\n" + "\n" +
                                 "Результат проверки заданий с КРАТКИМ ОТВЕТОМ: " + str(self.result_OGE) + "\n" +
                                 "Предварительная оценка за пробник ОГЭ: " + str(self.score) + "\n" +
                                 "Правильные ответы/ответы ученика: " + str(self.comparison_responses) + "\n" + "\n" +
                                 "Дата проведения (ДД-ММ-ГГ): " + self.student_answers[12] + "\n" + "Регион: " +
                                 self.student_answers[13] + "\n" + "Код ОО: " + self.student_answers[14]
                                 + "\n" + "Номера класса: " + self.student_answers[15] + "\n" + "Буква класса: " +
                                 self.student_answers[16] + "\n" + "Код пункта проведения: " + self.student_answers[
                                     17] +
                                 "\n" + "Номер аудитории" + self.student_answers[18] + "\n" + "Номер варианта: "
                                 + self.student_answers[19] + "\n" + "Код предмета: " + self.student_answers[20] +
                                 "\n" + "Название предмета: " + self.student_answers[21] + "\n" + "Номер КИМ: "
                                 + self.student_answers[22] + "\n" + "Фамилия учащегося: " + self.student_answers[23] +
                                 "\n" + "Имя учащегося: " + self.student_answers[24] + "\n" + "Очество учащегося: " +
                                 self.student_answers[25] + "\n" + "Серия паспорта: " + self.student_answers[26]
                                 + "\n" + "Номер паспорта: " + self.student_answers[27] + "\n" +
                                 "ВНИМАНИЕ ДАННАЯ ВЕРСИЯ ПРОГРАММА НАХОДИТСЯ В БЕТА ТЕСТИРОВАНИЕ." + "\n" +
                                 "В НЕЙ МОГУТ ПРЕСУДСТВОВАТЬ НЕ РАБОЧИЕ ФУНКЦИИ" + "\n" +
                                 "ПО ВОПРОСАМ УЛУЧШЕНИЯ ПО ОБРАЩАТСЯ НА ЭЛЕКТРОННУЮ ПОЧТУ: kb_orbit@mail.ru"
                                 )

            record_in_file.close()

            file_order += 1
            print(file_order)

            self.student_answers.clear()


    def information(self):
        if not os.path.exists('key_pub.pem'):
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("Ошибка")
            msg.setInformativeText('ВНИМАНИЕ! Публичный ключ не найден'
                                   'Попробуйте сгенерировать новый ключ.')
            msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
            msg.exec_()
            return

        with open('key_pub.pem', "rb") as f:
            _key_pub = f.read()

        key_pub = self.key_pub.load_pkcs1(_key_pub)

        #   self.bit_key = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        self.directory_key_check = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        self.name_file_key = self.lineEdit_16.text()
        #   self.directory_check_file = self.lineEdit_17

        self.key_task(key_pub)

    def key_task(self, key_pub):
        self.number_1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.number_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.number_3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.number_4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        self.number_5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.number_6 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.number_7 = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        self.number_8 = self.lineEdit_8.text()
        self.number_9 = self.lineEdit_9.text()
        self.number_10 = self.lineEdit_10.text()
        self.number_11 = self.lineEdit_11.text()
        self.number_12 = self.lineEdit_12.text()

        self.key_task_crypto(key_pub)

    def key_task_crypto(self, key_pub):
        self.number_1_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_1.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_2_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_2.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_3_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_3.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_4_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_4.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_5_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_5.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_6_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_6.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_7_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_7.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_8_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_8.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_9_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_9.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_10_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_10.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_11_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_11.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_12_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_12.encode('utf8'), key_pub)

        self.load_key_task_crypto()

    def load_key_task_crypto(self):
        k = [self.number_1_crypto, self.number_2_crypto, self.number_3_crypto, self.number_4_crypto,
             self.number_5_crypto, self.number_6_crypto, self.number_7_crypto, self.number_8_crypto,
             self.number_9_crypto, self.number_10_crypto, self.number_11_crypto, self.number_12_crypto]

        directory_save_key = self.directory_key_check + self.name_file_key

        with open(directory_save_key, "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join(base64.b64encode(item).decode('utf8') for item in k))

        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setText("Информация")
        msg.setInformativeText('Данные ключей ответов сохранены')
        msg.setWindowTitle("Информация")
        msg.exec_()

    def app_key_task(self):
        if not os.path.exists('key_priv.pem'):
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("Ошибка")
            msg.setInformativeText('ВНИМАНИЕ! Приватный ключ не найден'
                                   'Попробуйте сгенерировать новый ключ.')
            msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
            msg.exec_()
            return

        with open('key_priv.pem', "rb") as f:
            _key_priv = f.read()

        self.key_priv = self.key_priv.load_pkcs1(_key_priv)

        directory_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, ".", "*.txt")
        if not directory_file:
            return

        with open(directory_file, "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            decrypted = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(line.strip()), self.key_priv)

            self.answers.append(decrypted.decode('utf8'))
            print(self.answers)

        name_file = os.path.basename(directory_file)
        directory_file = os.path.dirname(directory_file) + "/"

        self.lineEdit.setText(self.answers[0])
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(self.answers[1])
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(self.answers[2])
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(self.answers[3])
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(self.answers[4])
        self.lineEdit_6.setText(self.answers[5])
        self.lineEdit_7.setText(self.answers[6])
        self.lineEdit_8.setText(self.answers[7])
        self.lineEdit_9.setText(self.answers[8])
        self.lineEdit_10.setText(self.answers[9])
        self.lineEdit_11.setText(self.answers[10])
        self.lineEdit_12.setText(self.answers[11])

        self.lineEdit_14.setText(directory_file)
        self.lineEdit_16.setText(name_file)

    def func_generate_keys(self):
        save_key_pub = self.key_pub.save_pkcs1()
        with open('key_pub.pem', "wb") as f:
            f.write(save_key_pub)

        save_key_priv = self.key_priv.save_pkcs1()
        with open('key_priv.pem', "wb") as f:
            f.write(save_key_priv)

        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setText("Информация")
        msg.setInformativeText('Ключи шифрования и дешифровки созданны.'
                               'Отправте публичный ключ участникам ОГЭ')
        msg.setWindowTitle("Информация")
        msg.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()

)
```